# I am able to read the txt line by line, buy not sure how can I now search and replace perticular string with X

Tags: python

I am currently trying to develop a python script to sanitize configuration. My objective is to read line by line from txt, which I could using following code

```
fh = open('test.txt')
for line in fh:
    print(line)
fh.close()
```

output came up as follows

```
hostname
198.168.1.1
198.168.1.2
snmp string abck
```

Now I want to

1. Search the string matching "hostname" replace with X
2. Search the ipv4 addresses using regular expression 
   `\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(?1)){3}\b and replace with X.X\1 (replacing only first two octets with X)`
3. Aything after "snmp string" need to replaced with X

so the file final output I am looking for is

```
X
x.x.1.1
x.x.1.2
snmp string x
```

I could not orchestrate everything together. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of approaches to this, but here's one: rather than just printing each line of the file, store each line in a list:

```
with open("test.txt") as fh:
   contents = []
   for line in fh:
      contents.append(line)

print(contents)
```

Now you can loop through that list in order to perform your regex operations. I'm not going to write that code for you, but you can use python's [inbuilt regex library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).